# How do I fetch record from mysql order by parent child from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, parent-child

I have one Mysql table contains records includes 2 types of records

1.parent record and

2.Child record

```
ID       |  ParentID    |    Feature
1        |  0           |   abc    
2        |  0           |  baby 
3        |  2           |  cart
4        |  1           |  Daddy
5        |  2           |  george
6        |  1           |  Frank
```

There is one column `ParentID` which differentiate parent from child. Parent have value of that column `NULL` whereas in that column child have id of there parent.Id column is auto increment.

So my question is I need latest record which in following order
On top parent record should be there after that child of that parent should appear.

So recordset will be as follow

```
FeatureID | ParentID 
1            0       
4            1      
6            1      
2            0     
3            2      
5            2
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
order by case when ParentID = 0 then ID else ParentID end, ParentID, ID
```

1. order by a computed column that is the ParentID or ID
2. order by ParentID
3. oder by ID

whether you use ANSI/ISO-standard `case when ... then ... else ... end` or the shorter MySQL specific `if(...,...,...)` depends on your liking. Also whether you you use `ParentID=0` or inverse logic to `ParentID!=0` (the later can be shortened in this case to just `ParentID`)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this should work:

```
...
ORDER BY IF(ParentID,ParentID,ID) ASC, ID ASC
```

Comment: more accurate results using `ORDER BY IF(ParentID,ParentID,ID), ParentID, ID`